# Update an ASP.NET label without AJAX.NET or jQuery

Tags: asp.net, ajax

The form has one asp:label and one html input button.
On the button click, I want to update the label (e.g. some server side data).

I would like to do this without UpdatePanel or jQuery.
I can do a basic ajax call to an .aspx on the button click.
What is the best way to update the label with the result? [figure it has to be an asp:label]

Do I need a hidden field which gets loaded with the label's ClientID on Page_Load?
Is there an easier way?

thx

Comment: Is the contents of the label known before the button is clicked?

Comment: It could be blank or filled in with something on Page_Load

Answer (score 4):

Just updated the innerHtml of the label. Emit the ClientID property somewhere to give you a back-reference to the object. IE:

```
doUpdate()
{
   var label = document.getElementById('<%= MyLabel.ClientID %>');
   label.innerHTML = getMyAjaxValue();
}
```

PS: one important thing to note is that this won't effect the page's viewstate, so if you are reading values from the label after postback, you are SOL. In that case, you might want to pair the label up with an ASP:Hidden control to capture the data.

Comment: this works when doUpdate() is placed in the actual .aspx, not when it is in a separate .js file.  Is that normal?  Also, I had to use double quotes...the single's gave errors.